# How to find URLs in a string that contains special chars using preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I tried a lot of rules for find a urls with preg_match(), that works fine with normal urls, but when i try to find a url with special chars like !, the url get cutted.

Example:

```
<?php 
$string = 'http://url.com/!abcd1234 http://url.com/#abcd1234 https://url.com/abcd1234 http://url.com/abcd1234 https://url.com/abc/d1234?123=123';
$rule='@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@';
$search = preg_match_all($rule, $string, $find);
foreach ($find[1] as $fn){
  echo $fn;
}
?>
```

Returns:

```
http://url.com/!
http://url.com/#abcd1234
https://url.com/abcd1234
http://url.com/abcd1234
https://url.com/abc/d1234?123=123
```

Seems works nice with all urls, but the first really is "http://url.com/!abcd1234" and only was returned until the ! char. I think because the ! char is a negation.

Exist a solution for don't get this problem? the urls can have the ! or not, that is my problem because the rule should works for all.

Thnks for reading :)

Comment: Shouldn't `!` be escaped when used in a path?

Comment: Also, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6878572/1338292) seems to work, in which case this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$rule='@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@';
```

with

```
$rule='@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#!-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@';
```

It's Working...